# Can't understand grammatical role of a particular clause from a sentence from Shardik by Richard Adams

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, parsing

> Along the foot of a tilted, red rock a porcupine came nosing and
>   grubbing. It broke open a tiny shelter of sticks and some meagre,
>   round-eared little creature, **all eyes and bony limbs**, fled across the
>   stones.

I can't understand a grammatical role of **all eyes and bony limbs**. It seems to be a description of those little creatures, but I feel that in this case there should be a participle or a verb: something like *round-eared little creature, all **are** eyes and bony limbs* emphasising that these body parts seem to be only ones they consist of (I think it is what the author meant); or some preposition tying the description to *little creatures*: *little creatures **with** eyes and bony limbs ...*.

Comment: "All" in this case basically means "entirely": the little creature is *entirely* eyes and bony limbs.  I'll let someone else explain the exact grammatical logic behind why there is no verb there; it might be a reduced relative clause, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: You might find it easier to grasp the syntax if you assume a "deleted" ***which was*** before the adjectival phrase (which could occur in a simpler sentence such as *The round-eared little creature **was** all eyes and bony limbs*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, summarising your comment and answer by JavaLatte could we say that skipping a verb is a device intended to *give a quick but vivid impression* about those little creatures?

Comment: I don't think there's any special reason to associate the usage with *giving a quick but vivid impression* any more than any other adjectival usage. Those associations arise simply because of the *semantics* of ***all X*** - where ***X*** can be any appropriate noun(s) or adjective(s). Thus *John stood there, all smiles* is just a common way of merging the two sentences *John stood there. John was all smiles* which makes it explicitly clear that both things were happening *at the same time* (they're not part of a "sequential narrative" where one thing follows another).

Comment: @fumblefingers, I think you are ignoring the idiomatic element to **all smiles**. It's not just merging two sentences describing two things happening at the same time: it's a vignette (if one is allowed to use that term on ELL). http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-all-smiles

Comment: @JavaLatte: I'm certainly not ignoring the significance of ***all smiles***, etc. I'm simply making the point that "skipping the verb" (which is what OP asked about) doesn't in and of itself represent a device for conveying a "quick but vivid impression". Come to that, I'm not even sure the word ***all*** necessarily carries a significant *semantic* payload. Whether or not to include it in, say, *[**All**] excited, John stood up* is really just a stylistic choice - it doesn't particularly affect the *meaning*.

Comment: ... and "all eyes and bony limbs" could not in a million years be mistaken for a literal statement of fact. It too is a vignette.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of idiomatic expressions like this... "I'm all ears", "I'm all fingers and thumbs",  and **all** is the cue that it is a vignette.

Answer (score -1):

"all noun1 and noun2" is an idiomatic way of giving a quick but vivid impression of something. Examples are:

> [all mouth and trousers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_mouth_and_trousers) - somebody who talks and acts manly but fails to live up to it
>
> all blood and thunder - melodromatic novels
>
> [all skin and bones](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-all-skin-and-bone-s) - somebody painfully thin

You will also see "all noun1 no noun2", for example

> all wax and no wick
>
> [All the gear, no idea](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/snowandski/725706/All-the-gear-but-no-idea.html) - somebody who has bought the latest equipment for a sport but is hopeless.
>
> [all meat no potatoes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all%20meat%20and%20no%20potatoes)

It is possible to use just "all noun1" as well.

> [all smiles](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+smiles) - for somebody who is unexpectedly cheerful

Comment: This is something called a phrase. That is the grammatical role of this structure. Several types of phrases exists, such as noun phrases, participial phrases, gerund phrases... They do not necessarily contain a verb, unlike clauses. In your case this is a noun phrase serving as a noun adjunct — it modifies "creature".